# How to parse xml itunes under item tag in rssfeed in php

Tags: php, json, xml, itunes

I want to parse itunes:image::href="#" from xml rss feed to json in php. I am able to get the title, PubDate etc. But unable to parse itunes..Please help
here is my rssfeed snippet.

```
 <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:itunes="http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
      <channel>
        <atom:link href="http://feeds.soundcloud.com/users/soundcloud:users:61234965/sounds.rss" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml"/>
        <atom:link href="http://feeds.soundcloud.com/users/soundcloud:users:61234965/sounds.rss?before=288739617" rel="next" type="application/rss+xml"/>
        <title>The Safina Society Podcast</title>
        <link>http://www.safinasociety.org</link>
        <pubDate>Mon, 05 Mar 2018 02:43:02 +0000</pubDate>
        <lastBuildDate>Mon, 05 Mar 2018 02:43:02 +0000</lastBuildDate>
        <ttl>60</ttl>
        <language>en</language>
        <copyright>All rights reserved</copyright>
        <webMaster>feeds@soundcloud.com (SoundCloud Feeds)</webMaster>
        <description>This life is but a transitory test, and the ultimate success in this life is reaching its end having fulfilled Allah’s commands with a good heart and avoided His major prohibitions. At Safina Society we seek to offer the faithful the knowledge and companionship that will assist in traversing the test of life and reaching its end safely. 

It is our hope that these podcasts, classes and gatherings will spark a movement, of renewed intention, renewed study, renewed commitment to our sacred law, as well as renewed love of our Lord.</description>
        <itunes:subtitle>This life is but a transitory test, and the ultim…</itunes:subtitle>
        <itunes:owner>
          <itunes:name>Safina Society</itunes:name>
          <itunes:email>muin.saiyed@safinasociety.org</itunes:email>
        </itunes:owner>
        <itunes:author>Safina Society</itunes:author>
        <itunes:explicit>no</itunes:explicit>
        <itunes:image href="http://i1.sndcdn.com/avatars-000285408508-ih0xcy-original.jpg"/>
        <image>
          <url>http://i1.sndcdn.com/avatars-000285408508-ih0xcy-original.jpg</url>
          <title>Safina Society</title>
          <link>http://www.safinasociety.org</link>
        </image>
        <itunes:category text="Education"/>
        <item>
      <guid isPermaLink="false">tag:soundcloud,2010:tracks/408792456</guid>
      <title>S2:E13 - Water your Sun Plant</title>
      <pubDate>Mon, 05 Mar 2018 14:23:30 +0000</pubDate>
      <link>https://soundcloud.com/safina-society/03-01-18a</link>
      <itunes:duration>01:44:20</itunes:duration>
      <itunes:author>Safina Society</itunes:author>
      <itunes:explicit>no</itunes:explicit>
      <itunes:summary>Listen as on this episode the team visits some of history as we talk about the rise of Muslim Spain, it's fall and how we should understand civilizations. We also discuss the end of times and how we should handle ourselves, the ummah, and our imaan during the end of times.</itunes:summary>
      <itunes:subtitle>Listen as on this episode the team visits some of…</itunes:subtitle>
      <description>Listen as on this episode the team visits some of history as we talk about the rise of Muslim Spain, it's fall and how we should understand civilizations. We also discuss the end of times and how we should handle ourselves, the ummah, and our imaan during the end of times.</description>
      <enclosure type="audio/mpeg" url="http://feeds.soundcloud.com/stream/408792456-safina-society-03-01-18a.mp3" length="150229913"/>
      <itunes:image href="http://i1.sndcdn.com/artworks-000311333859-zttwpu-original.jpg"/>
    </item>
      </channel>
    </rss>
```

i want to get itunes:image href=".....i am unable to get data with

Comment: please add a little more detail - the rss feed and what you have so far

Comment: i have updated my question, Please check..Thanks in advance

Comment: that snippet of xml/rss omits the schema/namespace declaration and you have not included any php or javascript code used so far to process this. Are you using PHP DOMDocument and XPath, Javascript or some other library?

Comment: Thanks  RamRaider... I have updated the the code what i am getting into rss feed...Please check...thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have not declared the methods used to process the RSS feed I have made an assumption that it is `DOMDocument` and `DOMXPath` - so the trick is to use the namespace as declared in the RSS attributes by registering that / those namespaces.

You can of couse use a url rather than a local file but as I do not know the url I could not show that - but essentially the same.

```
<?php
    /*
        Assuming that a local ccopy of the RSS exists in the same directory as this script
    */
    $file=__DIR__.'/itunes.rss';
    $dom=new DOMDocument;
    $dom->load( $file );

    $xp=new DOMXPath( $dom );
    $xp->registerNamespace('itunes','http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd');
    $xp->registerNamespace('atom','http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom');

    $query='//item/itunes:image';
    $col=$xp->query( $query );

    if( $col->length > 0 ){

        foreach( $col as $node ) echo $node->getAttribute('href');

    }

?>
```

outputs

```
http://i1.sndcdn.com/artworks-000311333859-zttwpu-original.jpg
```

---

With the url, gleaned from the rss itself:

```
$file='http://feeds.soundcloud.com/users/soundcloud:users:61234965/sounds.rss';

$dom=new DOMDocument;
$dom->load( $file );

$xp=new DOMXPath( $dom );
$xp->registerNamespace('itunes','http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd');
$xp->registerNamespace('atom','http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom');

$query='//item/itunes:image';
$col=$xp->query( $query );

if( $col->length > 0 ){

    foreach( $col as $node ) echo $node->getAttribute('href') . '<br />';

}
```

outputs:

```
http://i1.sndcdn.com/artworks-000311333859-zttwpu-original.jpg
http://i1.sndcdn.com/artworks-000307423581-cp3yz4-original.jpg
http://i1.sndcdn.com/artworks-000304937310-4lpxwt-original.jpg
http://i1.sndcdn.com/artworks-000303669636-ikttvf-original.jpg
http://i1.sndcdn.com/artworks-000303671391-egwsr9-original.jpg
http://i1.sndcdn.com/artworks-000292343751-dga5d4-original.jpg
http://i1.sndcdn.com/artworks-000287215952-jl1vmx-original.jpg
http://i1.sndcdn.com/artworks-000285476606-3fn1vc-original.jpg
http://i1.sndcdn.com/artworks-000280384667-f5o3rl-original.jpg
http://i1.sndcdn.com/artworks-000277395593-15vyp1-original.jpg
http://i1.sndcdn.com/avatars-000285408508-ih0xcy-origi..... etc etc
```

---

Modify the XPath query to select whatever tags you are interested in and process them however you need to. For example:

```
define('BR','<br />');/* for convenience */

$file='http://feeds.soundcloud.com/users/soundcloud:users:61234965/sounds.rss';

$dom=new DOMDocument;
$dom->load( $file );

$xp=new DOMXPath( $dom );
$xp->registerNamespace('itunes','http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd');
$xp->registerNamespace('atom','http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom');

/* add additional tags to the query */
$query='//item/itunes:image | //item/itunes:author | //item/guid  | //item/title | //item/itunes:duration | //item/enclosure';
$col=$xp->query( $query );

if( $col->length > 0 ){

    foreach( $col as $node ) {

        $tag = $node->tagName;
        $attr = $node->attributes;
        $value = $node->nodeValue;

        if( $attr->length > 0 ){

            if( $tag=='itunes:image' ) echo $node->getAttribute('href') . BR;
            if( $tag=='enclosure' ) printf('<a href="%s" target="_blank">%s</a>%s',$node->getAttribute('url'),$node->getAttribute('url'),BR);

        } else{

            printf('tag: %s ->  value: %s%s',$tag,$value,BR );
        }
    }
}
```

Will output:

```
tag: title  ->  value: Democracy & The Future of Liberalism: With Rashid Dar<br />
tag: itunes:duration    ->  value: 01:43:09<br />
tag: itunes:author  ->  value: Safina Society<br />
<a href="http://feeds.soundcloud.com/stream/412842882-safina-society-democracy-the-future-of-liberalism-with-rashid-dar.mp3" target="_blank">http://feeds.soundcloud.com/stream/412842882-safina-society-democracy-the-future-of-liberalism-with-rashid-dar.mp3</a><br />
http://i1.sndcdn.com/artworks-000315497973-5ksx4r-original.jpg<br />

tag: title  ->  value: S2:E13 - Water your Sun Plant<br />
tag: itunes:duration    ->  value: 01:44:20<br />
tag: itunes:author  ->  value: Safina Society<br />
<a href="http://feeds.soundcloud.com/stream/408792456-safina-society-03-01-18a.mp3" target="_blank">http://feeds.soundcloud.com/stream/408792456-safina-society-03-01-18a.mp3</a><br />
http://i1.sndcdn.com/artworks-000311333859-zttwpu-original.jpg

... etc
```

I'm sure you can figure how to add the other elements to the query given the above

Comment: Thanks RamRaider. Its working..!! But how to get other data with this image of an item?

Comment: `"how to get other data with this image of an item"` - please explan - I don't understand what you mean. Do you wish to get other items such as `itunes:author` or `itunes:subtitle` etc?

Comment: Yes i want to get itunes:author ,MP3 File,Duration,Title,description,
content,itunes:image and enclosure also like..items
0
title : "Democracy & The Future of Liberalism: With Rashid Dar"
link : "https://soundcloud.com/safina-society/democracy-the-future-of-liberalism-with-rashid-dar"
description : "Democracy & The Future of Liberalism: With Rashid Dar by Safina Society"
description_text : "Democracy & The Future of Liberalism: With Rashid Dar by Safina Society"
pubDate : "Tue, 13 Mar 2018 02:06:45 +0000"..in a json format.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php echo $node->children('itunes', true)->image->attributes()->href;?>
```

Comment: shubham ralli, while this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.